# Apt-get throwing invalid statoverride uid #

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apt-get

When I run apt-get, all of a sudden I keep getting this error, I'm not able to figure out what is causing it, this is a standard Ubuntu 18.04:

```
# apt-get install -V apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
   apt-transport-https (1.6.10 => 1.6.12)
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 244 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1692 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 invalid statoverride uid #
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
#
```

Comment: [This post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=173935) suggests to use **sudo sed -i '/root/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride** and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/548996/syntax-error-unknown-user-munin-in-statoverride-file) also seems helpful.

Comment: I ran sudo sed -i '/root/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride, no change, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by some serious filesystem corruption and I believe disk failure. The /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride file had content from a completely different file